# Strange HTTP authentication issue

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, digest-authentication

I'm experiencing issues when trying to communicate with a web server (Apache 2.2.17) using Digest authentication, and sending data with the POST method: it always returns a 401 error. However, it works well when we don't post data, or when Fiddler is running (even when posting data)...Do you have an idea of what can cause the problem?

```
public void DoRequest(string v_strURL, XmlDocument v_objXMLDoc)
{

var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();

credentialCache.Add(new Uri("http://" + ServerIP + "/"), "Digest", new NetworkCredential("admin", "test", "realm"));

String RequestContent = "request=" + v_objXMLDoc.InnerXml.Replace(' ', '+');
Uri Url = new Uri(v_strURL);

HttpWebRequest objHttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse objHttpWebResponse = null;

Stream objRequestStream = null;

byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RequestContent);

objHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(v_strURL);
objHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "MySampleCode";
objHttpWebRequest.Credentials = credentialCache;
objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
objHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

objRequestStream = objHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
objRequestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
objRequestStream.Close();

objHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

}
```

Comment: please show some source code and compare what goes over the wire (with and without fiddler) for example with wireshark...

Comment: You need to show source code, I've written lots of C# code that posts data using HTTP and digest authentication which is in production use and works without issue. So either your code has some bugs in it or there is a server configuration problem, without sample code/more details it is impossible to tell!

Comment: I will post the source code as soon as possible!

Comment: Edit: source code added.

Comment: thanks for the source.. have you compared what goes over the wire (with wireshark) when it works and when it doesn't ?

Comment: @RobV: glad you confirmed that HTTP should work properly ;)

Comment: Actually I'm not working directly on this project, and the developer has not sent the Wireshark logs to me yet...

Comment: @duedl0r I was trying to explain to the OP as a new user why their question needed more detail, "I do X and get error Y" with no source code and minimal detail is rarely a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally have solved the problem:

```
objHttpWebRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there some reason you're setting the Content-Type header twice? That isn't likely to do what you want it to do. Also, why do you put the creds in the cache with the server IP rather than the hostname?

The HTTP/401 suggests that the server is challenging the client for credentials. The client is expected to respond by resubmitting the request with credentials attached. One key question is, in the failing case is the client trying to send the credentials and they're rejected, or not trying to send the credentials at all?

You probably should use Netmon or Wireshark for a lower-level look if Fiddler is "magically" fixing the problem for you.

Comment: Sorry, setting the Content-Type header twice is a mistake. The server IP is the only information we have...To answer your key question, yes the client tries to send the credentials and they're rejected.

Comment: I *think* you're saying that the Server IP is what you have in the URL, instead of a hostname? Also, can you provide a sample URL (e.g. are there query string parameters) and the tokens in the server's Digest challenge (e.g. is it configured for integrity?)

Answer (score 1):

Is the hostname in your HttpWebRequest.Create() call (i.e v_strUrl) the same as the hostname in the call to credentialCache.Add() ( i.e ServerIP ) ? If not, then this is going to fail always.

Instead of using CredentialCache, just add credentials directly to the HttpWebRequest object

> request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "realm");

and see if that works.